# How to use awk or sed to get text between two words

Tags: awk, sed

I have string lists :

```
./SolutionController.php core/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/SolutionController.php
./ContentController.php core/app/Http/Controllers/Frontpage/ContentController.php
./country-flag vendor/country-flag
```

I wish I could get the final value between the './' sign and the 'space'

Output:

```
SolutionController.php
ContentController.php
country-flag
```

This code with bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tanggal=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
filename="./update/$tanggal/lists.md"
n=1
tanggalWaktu=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
mkdir -p ./logs

while read line; do
    fileName=$(awk -F'[/ ]' '{print $2}' $line) 
    echo "file -> $fileName"
done < $filename
```

Output:

```
awk: can't open file ./SolutionController.php
 source line number
```

Please help me

Comment: A parameter expansion can extract what you want from that output as well. Also if the output is coming from `find` and your `find` has the `printf` flag then use it to format the output that you desire.

Comment: If you're going to use awk then don't embed it inside a while read loop. something like. `while read ....; do ...; done < <(awk  -F'[/ ]' '{print $2}' "$filename")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk :

```
awk -F'[/ ]' '{print $2}' string.txt
```

Using gawk:

```
awk '{print gensub(/\.\/(.*) (.*)/,"\\1","g")}' string.txt
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat string.txt 
./SolutionController.php core/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/SolutionController.php
./ContentController.php core/app/Http/Controllers/Frontpage/ContentController.php
./country-flag vendor/country-flag  

$ awk -F'[/ ]' '{print $2}' string.txt 
SolutionController.php
ContentController.php
country-flag

$ awk '{print gensub(/\.\/(.*) (.*)/,"\\1","g")}' string.txt 
SolutionController.php
ContentController.php
country-flag
```

Comment: the code works but if you use the bash script why can't it work

Comment: @MohamadSholihin This will help you execute on your terminal `line="./SolutionController.php core/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/SolutionController.php"; fileName=$(awk -F'[/ ]' '{print $2}' <<<"$line"); echo "$fileName";`

Comment: @Akshay good job.. thanks..
can you help me for get string after space in this string lists?
expected output : 
core/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/SolutionController.php

Comment: @MohamadSholihin: `awk '{print gensub(/\.\/(.*) (.*)/,"\\2","g")}'  <<< "$line" `

Comment: this return:
awk: calling undefined function gensub
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1

Comment: @MohamadSholihin : `calling undefined function gensub`  because you don't have gawk, to get second part you can just use `line="./SolutionController.php core/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/SolutionController.php"; fileName=$(awk  '{print $2}' <<<"$line"); echo "$fileName"`

Comment: @Akshay good job, thanks brother its work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do it

```
echo "./SolutionController.php core/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/SolutionController.php" | sed -r 's/\.\/(.*) .*/\1/'
```

If you stored it in the file.

```
sed -r 's/\.\/(.*) .*/\1/' strings.txt
```

Comment: after try :
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: Show me your screen.

Comment: This might be the case of different `sed` variant. `GNU` and `BSD`

Comment: @Jetchisel: yep